# putting my aiml code to run on pycharm, the '^' doesn't work

Tags: pycharm, chatbot, aiml, pandorabots

Was coding aiml chatbots on pandorabots, and use the '^' frequently.

But when I put my aiml code to run on pycharm, the '^' doesn't work, as it was going to match 0 or more words, it's going to be problem.

And seems like many tags of aiml aren't available outside of pandorabots, like the  tag.

Have anyone solved this?

Newbie here, thanks in advance!

Comment: ^ is a new wildcard introduced in AIML 2. I assume pycharm isn't AIML 2 compatible? If not, you will need to amend your categories to use the old * wildcard (matches 1 or more words). For an AIML 2 interpreter, I would advise looking at Program AB. It's not actively developed any more but is what I use for the Loebner Prize and works with all AIML 2.0 features.

Comment: You can deploy your Pandorabot onto other channels, but this is unavailable with a free account. There's more info and a download of Program AB here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/